# Knockout JS and passing in an already existing Array

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I call an API which retrieves and parses the JSON, At this point I have instantiated LIST3 and I am trying to pass this array of objects into the ko.observable function. I have followed the tutorials and seemed to be stumped here.

If I pass the values in manually using a constructor as the tutorial suggests I can display the data, so the logic seems ok. Am I trying to do something which KO is unable perform?

CODE

```
var LIST3 = [];
var coreUrl = "https://cors.io/?http://rundistance.azurewebsites.net/api/";
var listUrl = coreUrl + "RunnerService";

$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $.getJSON(listUrl)
                .done(function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        LIST3.push(item);
                        });
                      });
                    });

function addRunner(){

var self = this;

self.runner = ko.observableArray(LIST3);

}

ko.applyBindings(new addRunner());
```

Markup

```
<div class = "unit3 unit">
    <h1>Drawing from Web API and Display with Knockout.JS</h1>
    <h3>Results</h3>
    <div id = "detail3">
      <p id = "name3"></p>
      <p id = "LRDistance3"></p>
      <p id = "LRTime3"></p>
      <p id = "LRDate3"></p>
    </div>
    <table id = "unit" data-bind = "foreach: runner">
      <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: RunnerName"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what's `i` in `function (i, item)` can you try replacing this with `function (item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is loading up the local array LIST3 after it has been assigned to the `self.runner` observable array. You need to load the observable array directly from the results of the $.getJSON call.

```
var coreUrl = "https://cors.io/?http://rundistance.azurewebsites.net/api/";
var listUrl = coreUrl + "RunnerService";

$(document).ready(function () {
    function AddRunner(){
        var self = this;
        self.runner = ko.observableArray([]);

        function loadRunner() {
            $.getJSON(listUrl)
                    .done(function (data) {
                        self.runner(data);
                    });
        }

        loadRunner();
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new AddRunner());
}
```

Comment: So based on this, I should then  ensure the markup has a data-bind on for each runner.

Comment: @SimonDean Yes, your markup with the `data-bind="foreach: runner"` and then the text binding for the `RunnerName` should work assuming there is a property named `RunnerName` on each runner.

Answer (score 1):

LIST3 isn't an observable array so pushing new items into it will not cause an update. You create an observable array from list3 called runner. I suggest you push your items into runner instead or make LIST3 an observable array from the beginning.

```
var LIST3 = ko.observableArray([]);

$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $.getJSON(listUrl)
            .done(function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    LIST3.push(item);
                });
            });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I knew I was going in the right direction.